# crosswalk cordova 32 & 64 bits

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

i try to build apks with 32 & 64 bits using crosswalk
my config is :
Cordova Android 8.1.0

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="^2.4.0">
<variable name="XWALK_COMMANDLINE" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
<variable name="XWALK_MODE" value="embedded" />
<variable name="XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK" value="true" />
<variable name="XWALK_VERSION" value="23+" />
</plugin>
```

i got 5 apks : arm64, armeabi, armv7, x86, x86_64

the problem is that the **armv7 & x86** apks are **not 64 bits** and get rejected by google play console.
how can i solve this problem ?
thanks

Comment: See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-v3

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide native assembly for `armeabi-v7a` & `arm64-v8a` - and nothing else.

While `x86` & `x86_64` are only good for debugging with the Android emulator.

See [support 64-bit architectures](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit).

Comment: what you mean by only good for debugging with the Android emulator?
do i need to send them to google play?

Comment: @user3341841 Have you read my answer - or maybe had a look at the link?